# ComboBoxCell Value is not valid

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview binded to a BindingList and inside this list I have comboboxes binded to a list which is a property of my BindingList, for understanding better:

> ListA ---> binded to datagridview
>
> ListA.ListB ---> binded to comboboxes

When I open the form I can corectly set my comboboxes showing the values inside the ListB, but when I add a new item I get an error (value is not valid), here is the code:

```
private void dataGridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView.Columns["Names"]).DisplayIndex = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < People.Count; i++)
    {
        var cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Names"];
        cell.DataSource = People[i].Names;
        cell.Value = People[i].Names[0];
    }
}
```

The code above works great, the problem happens here:

```
private void dataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex != dataGridView.Columns["Names"].Index)
        return;
    var cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridViewICAO.CurrentCell;
    if (cell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString().Equals(String.Empty)) return;
    var regex = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]");
    if (!regex.IsMatch(cell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString()))
        e.Cancel = true;
    else
    {
        People[cell.RowIndex].Names.Add(cell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString());
        cell.Value = People[cell.RowIndex].Names.Last();
        People[cell.RowIndex].Names = cell.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

on the row code `cell.Value = People[cell.RowIndex].Names.Last();` I get the exception... Thanks to all!

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid

Comment: Add the details you've added into the comment and answer you posted to your question via editing it: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36334193/edit

Answer (score 0):

This is how I set the combobox:

```
private void AddComboBox()
    {
        var comboNames = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn { Name = "cmbNames", HeaderText = "Names" };
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(comboNames);
    }

private void dataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == dataGridView.Columns["cmbNames"].Index)
            {
                var combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
                if (combo == null)
                    return;

                combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            }
        }
```